# Prove $P(A^c \cap B^c) = P(A^c)P(B^c)$ using indicator functions

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

We have the indicator functions $$\mathbb{1}_A, \mathbb{1}_B$$ defined as usual. And we have $\mathbb{1}_A \leq a$ defined as

$$\mathbb{1}_A \leq a = \begin{cases} 
      \emptyset & a < 0 \\
      A^c & 0\leq a < 1 \\
      \Omega & a \geq 1 
   \end{cases}
$$ Similar for $\mathbb{1}_B$.

We want to prove, if we consider $\mathbb{1}_A, \mathbb{1}_B$ as independent random variables, then $$P(A^c \cap B^c) = P(A^c)P(B^c)$$ using the above mentioned indicator functions.

---

My attempt:

We have $P(A^c \cap B^c) = P(\mathbb{1}_A \leq 0, \mathbb{1}_B \leq 0) = P(\mathbb{1}_A \leq 0)P(\mathbb{1}_B \leq 0) = P(A^c)P(B^c)$

Does that seem correct ?

Comment: Yes. Also you could just write $\mathsf P(1_A=0\land 1_B=0)$ instead of $\mathsf P(1_A \le0\land 1_B\le0)$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Uh yeah right thanks. I just have one question remaining. $a$ could in fact be any value between $0$ and $1$ ($1$ excluded), it doesn't necessarily need to be $0$, we just use it for simplification, is that right ?

Comment: Yes, since the image of $1_A$ and $1_B$ is just $\{0,1\}$, the set $$1_A^{-1}(]-\infty,a])=\{\omega\in\Omega:1_A(\omega)\le a\}$$ is the same for all $0\le a<1$. However, I think this is a bit confusing and the argument is most clear if you just consider the set $$\{\omega\in\Omega:1_A(\omega)=0\}=A^\complement$$ (and similarly for $B$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct.

Alternatively,
note that $I_A$ and $I_B$ are independent means by definition that the $\sigma$-fields $\sigma(I_A)$ and $\sigma(I_B)$ are independent. Since $A \in \sigma(I_A)$ and $B \in \sigma(I_B)$, it follows that $A^c,B^c$ are independent and thus

$$P(A^c\cap B^c) = P(A^c)P(B^c)$$